# STS - Running "spring run" cmd

Tags: spring, groovy, spring-tool-suite

I want to run a simple groovy script with "spring run" command within STS.

What extensions are necessary?  I've also installed Grails, Groovy 2.3 compiler and Groovy-Eclipse.

MyApp.groovy:

```
@Controller
class MyApp {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    @ResponseBody
    String message() {
        return "<h1>Hello World!</h1>"
    }
}
```

Comment: This question is unclear. What exactly You'd like to do? What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The current implementation of the command I think you are talking about assumes the script is called 'app.groovy'. So 'MyApp.groovy', 'Foo.groovy' etc. won't be detected as runnable by this launcher.

Reference: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ide/blob/3.6.3.RELEASE/plugins/org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot/plugin.xml#L123